# Filter data using orderBy flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to use orderBy to filter data from firestore but I got an error and I know
the problem but I don't know how to fix that with my code, because the problem is when I
go to the URL and create the index that mean I'll create for every user not just once.

I just want to orderBy the date descending.

is there a better way to solve this?.

My stream:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>? stream()=> _fireStore
      .collection("chatRooms")
      .where("participants.${widget.userModel.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
      .orderBy("date", descending: true)
      .snapshots();
```

[image]

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific use-case, I'd recommend adding an additional **array** field (say `participantIDs`) with the UIDs of the users. This field requires just a single index, and you can then use this condition for the use-case:

```
.where("participantIDs", arrayContains: widget.userModel.uid)
```

Adding additional data to allow specific use-cases is quite common in NoSQL databases. If you're new to that, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: Thank you Frank for your help, this is a great solution I thought about it but like that solution make my app restructuring again and it take a lot of time, I wish there is a simple way to fix it.